# One-to-one speech conversation dataset (Recorded over microphone)

Tags: resource-request, spoken-language, datasets

I need a publically available one-to-one speech conversation dataset recorded over the microphone, e.g., interview scenario or enquiry or call centre call answering.

Answer (score 1):

Searching the [Virtual Language Observatory](https://vlo.clarin.eu) maintained by the European [CLARIN ERIC](https://clarin.eu) is the way to go. Enter `conversation spoken` in the search slit and narrow down the search using the facets (e.g., by chosing a language). Here is a [bookmarked query](https://vlo.clarin.eu/search?q=conversation%20spoken&fqType=languageCode:or&fq=languageCode:code:eng&fqType=modality:or&fq=modality:spoken) on the VLO giving a lot of resources for English language.

Comment: Thanks for your help jknappen but the conversation of corpus is not recorded over microphone. I was looking for one-one-one spoken speech conversation, recorded over single microphone e.g. teacher and student interview case over microphone etc...

Comment: There are certainly conversations recorded with microphone quality (as opposed to phone line quality) found using the VLO. When you have more specific requirements, please edit your question and state them explicitly. Also note that you can add more search terms to search slit (e.g., *microphone*) to get more specific results.